# Map of undefined after deleting an item - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React and in this circumstance I feel like I should be using a lifecycle hook, but I'm not sure which. In the code below I am making a call to the API and retrieving the list of users object which contains another list of things they own called `members`. Like so:

[image]

When clicking the button 'Unlink' I am then storing the reference in state and posting that back up to the API to unlink the member:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import FormScene from 'nwiadmin/scenes/form';
import Button from 'nwiadmin/components/button';

import { formatDate } from 'nwiadmin/utility/formatters';
import Modal from 'nwiadmin/components/modal';
import ModalActions from 'nwiadmin/components/modal/modalactions';

import SingleBusinesses from 'app/components/businesses';

let businessRef = '';

class UserBusinessSingleScene extends FormScene {
    /* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
    setInitialState(props) {
        const pendingData = {
            ...props.data,
        };
        const reference = businessRef;
        const isVisible = false;
        this.setReferenceTarget = this.setReferenceTarget.bind(this);

        return {
            pendingData,
            reference,
            isVisible,
        };
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('should cmp update', nextProps, nextState);
        return true;
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('cmp will update', nextProps, nextState);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('cmp did update', prevProps, prevState);
    }

    setLabel(data) {
        return data.name;
    }

    setMethod() {
        return 'post';
    }

    setRemote() {
        return `businesses/unclaim?reference=${this.state.reference}`;
    }

    modalToggleHander() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isVisible: !prevState.isVisible,
        }));
    }

    setReferenceTarget() {
        this.setState({ reference: businessRef });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.reference);
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.state.pendingData.members.map(business => (
                    <SingleBusinesses
                        key={business.reference}
                        name={business.name}
                        reference={business.reference}
                        claimed={`Claimed on: ${formatDate(business.created_at)}`}
                        unlink={
                            <Button
                                onClick={() => {
                                    businessRef = business.reference;
                                    this.setReferenceTarget();
                                    this.modalToggleHander();
                                }}
                            >
                                Unlink User
                            </Button>
                        }
                    />
                ))}
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.isVisible} title="Are you sure you want to unlink the user?">
                    <ModalActions
                        submit={() => this.submit()}
                        submitText="Unlink User"
                        cancel={() => this.modalToggleHander()}
                    />
                </Modal>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default UserBusinessSingleScene;
```

Once unlinked I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error. I'm not 100% sure why but I feel like it's something to do with the state and that I should be setting the state after unlinking? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are try to iterate over `undefined`. log your iterator and see why it is `undefined`. 

undefined is coming from - `this.state.pendingData.members`

Comment: It's not `undefined` initially. It only becomes `undefined` after setting the `reference` and posting to `businesses/unclaim?reference=${this.state.reference}` - it's as if it's looking for the original state and not finding the unlinked user? I'm unable to log the iterator since it's undefined.

Comment: log the entire object. You might be overriding the entire object.

Comment: Oh! You seem to be right:

`https://i.gyazo.com/4a1e3b67020e6ade63066a86536bfccd.png`

It does somehow overwrite the state to be empty? Any idea from the above code how it's managing to do that?

Comment: `this.setState({ reference: businessRef });` is culprit. You can use `Object.assign` to merge your updated object with existing object.

Comment: Interesting, where would the implementation for that be exactly? I just tried implementing it as follows: `const pendingData = Object.assign({ ...props.data });` with no change. Not sure if this is the right approach?

Comment: Does it work? If yes, then don't worry. Do refactor later. :)